# Send Gmail programmatically using Auth Cookie

Tags: android, authentication, oauth, gmail

I would like to implement something similar to the solution presented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-android-ap) that allows an application to send an email without using the `ACTION_SEND` Intent. However, rather than prompting the user for their gmail credentials, I'd rather use the AccountsManager class to allow access to the google account with one-click approval.

I'm familiar with how to get the the auth token/cookie once the user permits access to their account, but what I cant find information on (if it's at all possible) is how to authenticate and send email given that auth cookie rather than username and password. Any info on how to do this / if it's even possible would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: cmcowart, did you ever find a solution to this? I am in the same boat and still looking for an answer. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Since my above post was deleted, and I can't "undelete" it, I'm not sure if my edited reply is visible. So, I'm duplicating it here.

---

Here is a project that allows you to connect to GMail using OAuth authentication:

http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-xoauth-tools/

I haven't had a chance to actually try it out, but it may at least get you started in the right direction. Hopefully.